# python function error with sqlite code

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def readswitch(x,y,connn,read):
    x='create vlan'
    y='global'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return run;


for row in read:
     print (readswitch())
```

I am going to search x and y in my database and I want it to return my sql statement for the command

but it seems cant run this function like

```
for row in read:
NameError: name 'read' is not defined
```

can anyone fix this error?

Comment: is read actually in scope at your for loop? if thats your entire code, read is not defined anywhere except in the function.

Comment: @chris  I got your meaning but I dun t know what should I fix can you show me some example? thank you

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; 'read' has not been defined in the scope of your 'for' loop.  You defined a 'read' variable inside your function, but that scope can't be seen outside.  Also, unrelated, your function takes 4 arguments but you're going to call it with none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems, including argument passing and variable scope.  I'm not sure what it's really trying to do.  I suggest rewriting it with no function, just straight sequential execution.  Once you get that working, try to pull out the function call.

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, I don't expect this to satisfy the OP who likely has no idea what you are talking about. Thanks for trying though. (±0)